# Coding Puzzle for computer science project

Tags: python, python-2.7

i am doing a coding puzzle for a computer science project.

I was doing ok until i came across an indent block error. It is coming on line 63.

Any help would be brilliant!!!

Here is the code:

```
#check to see if letters used
while True:
    try:
        x=words.index(answer1)
        answer2=raw_input('Now please type the letter you wish to replace it with')
        words=words.replace(answer1,answer2)
    except ValueError:
        print "there is an error using this letter/symbol, try again"
        break
    answer2=raw_input('Now please type the letter you wish to replace it with')
    words=words.replace(answer1,answer2)
    if words==check:
        print"Congratulations"
    else:
        #routine to delete a previous guess


        #find  #if answer1=="+":
                #if answer2=="C"
                # +=C
        #words2=words.replace(answer1,answer2)
```

Comment: which one is line 63 in this code sample?

Comment: Any idea where line 63 is? My guess: you commented out all lines in the `else` clause and didn't use a `pass` statement.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `else` block. In Python, indentation matters, so no block can be completely empty. If the `else` statement is intended to do nothing, write

```
else:
    pass
```